# Delete line from a text file that contains any string from another file using sed/awk/etc

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm a bit of a total beginner when it comes to programming and I appreciate all help you are willing to provide.

Here's my problem...

I have a data.txt file with a lot of lines in it and a strings.txt that contains some strings (1 string per line).

I want to delete all lines from data.txt if they contain any string from strings.txt and to save that new file as proc_data.txt.

I know that I could use sed to search and delete for 1 or more strings but having 500+ strings to type in a CLI makes it ... well, you know.

What I've tried so far

```
~$ for i in `cat strings.txt`; do sed '/${i}/d' data.txt -i.bak; done
```

but it just makes a backup of data.txt with the same size.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep -v -f strings.txt data.txt >proc_data.txt
```

It searches all strings of `strings.txt` in `data.txt` with switch `-f`. Reverse the result adding `-v`. Redirect output to your desired file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for pointing me in the other direction :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor an [use LC_ALL=C](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssh/speed-up-grep-searches-with-lc-all) (and maybe fgrep if you're not using regex). Orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @orangechicken: Interesting link. Fixed my answer.